# How do I make a delete route for multiple items with Node js + Express + MySQL?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Trying to delete an group of items coming from the client by their sku code.

```
import express from 'express';
import { pool } from './mysql';
import cors from 'cors';
import { config } from 'dotenv';

config();
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS");
    next();
})

app.use(cors());

app.delete('/delete/:sku', (request:any, response:any) => {
    const sku = request.params.sku;
    pool.getConnection((err:any, connection:any) => {
        
        connection.query(
            'DELETE FROM products WHERE sku IN (?)',
            [sku],
            (error:any, result:any, fields:any) => {
                connection.release();
                if (error) {
                    return response.status(400).json(error)
                }
                response.status(200).json({success: true});
            }
            )
        })
    });

app.listen(4000);
```

The mysql.ts file is working for other routes but I can edit it in if someone think it's necessary.

postman is sending this:

```
localhost:4000/delete?sku=JVC200123&sku=JVC200124
```

and receiving this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot DELETE /delete</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

All other postman requests work without the http://. Not sure where is my mistake.

Comment: There might be multiple issues here.   Does the mysql library support binding an array as a parameter?  Most database drivers won't handle it like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you have a mistake for that express route in this piece of code

```
app.delete('/delete/:sku', (request:any, response:any) => {
   const sku = request.params.sku;
   ...rest of your code
});
```

it should be:

```
app.delete('/delete', (request:any, response:any) => {
    const sku = request.query.sku;
   ...rest of your code
});
```

The `localhost:4000/delete?sku=JVC200123&sku=JVC200124` is pointing to `/delete` and not `/delete/:sku` route. So the `:sku` path variable is redundant in your case since you want to go with query params for multiple items. Also, in order to access query params you need to use `request.query`

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that [request.params](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) refers to the *path* part of the route.

[request.query](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.query) is what you want.

request.query can return a string, undefined, or an array. You want an array in every case, be it an empty array (nothing was passed in), an array of one element (request.query is a string), or an array of multiple strings (a request of the form `/delete?sku=AAAA&sku=BBBB&sku=CCCC` was sent)

Therefore, you want a helper function to normalize the input:

```
const normalizeToArray = (inputValue: any): string[] => {
    let r: string[] = [];
    if (typeof inputValue === "string") {
        r.push(inputValue)
    }
    if (Array.isArray(inputValue)) {
        r = inputValue;
    }
    return r;
};
```

And your express route should look like this:

```
app.delete('/delete', (request: express.Request, response: express.Response) => {

    //  ensure that skus is always an array, no matter what gets passed in
    const skus = normalizeToArray( request.query.sku || [] );

    pool.getConnection((err: MysqlError, connection: PoolConnection) => {
        connection.query(
            'DELETE FROM products WHERE sku IN (?)',
            skus,
            (error: any, result: any, fields: any) => {
                connection.release();
                if (error) {
                    return response.status(400).json(error)
                }
                response.status(200).json({ success: true });
            }
        )
    })
});
```

I highly recommend using stricter Typescript types. It enables really helpful intellesence capabilities in your IDE.

Comment: Oh, thank you, typing better is one of my learning priorities. Will stop with the lazy "anys" sometime soon. Also don't want to be greedy and ask questions in comments but... Normalizing to arrays sounds important, could I know why? (will upvote this after I get 15 rep)

Comment: in your particular use-case it looks like you want to normalize to an array, because that's what your `connection.query()` is expecting. SQL of the form `SELECT * FROM table WHERE field IN (?)` expects an array, which could be represented by comma-seperated values or a sub-query